# How can I use 2 different background between landscape mode and portrait mode

Tags: android

I have an android application, I would like to know if I can have 1 layout (1 layout xml file) for both landscape and portrait mode. But I want a different background for each mode? Is that possible? Do I need 2 xml file points to different background image? Or I can achieve what I want using 1 xml file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're willing to use code to accomplish this, you might try inserting something like

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background_carrying_view);
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.background_land);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.background_port);
}
```

into your onCreate() and/or onConfigurationChange().

With this method, you would use the same layout for both landscape and portrait.

Comment: This works but I'd personally use 'View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();'

Comment: You can always define two separate xml layouts as well. One for portrait and one for landscape.

Comment: Yes, of course; it just seems the OP wanted to avoid this. :)

Comment: if you use it from onConfigurationChange(), the Configuration object is already passed as a parameter, so it is a bit simpler

Answer (score 21):

I have achieved the same by creating *drawable-land-hdpi* folder and copying my landscape background into it.

I did not want to change my code, I just have one XML layout file and two different background.jpg images in two folders *drawable-land-hdpi* and *drawable-hdpi*.

Comment: just if anybody runs into the same problems: in order to use this you must not have android:configChanges="orientation" set in the manifest for your activity, otherwise the current activity is not destroyed and resources reinitialized from the corresponding directories... here is a description of all modifiers you can use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation" set in the manifest for your activity

Comment: This is the right approach and yes, android:configChanges="orientation" must not be used.