# Splash Screen Image for landscape and Portrait using Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-theme

I have two full screens splash images, one is for landscape and another is for portrait mode.I want to implemented theses images as splash as per the orientation of the device when app starts.

For Example if app starts from landscape mode than landscape image should be displayed as background image and if app starts from portrait mode than portrait image should be displayed as background image
I have refer the following [Example](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

This is how i setup the **Theme**:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_1</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

I set this theme for splash activity from **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Two show land and port images i have place two images with same name `splash_screen_1.jpg` images in `drawable-land-hdpi` and `drawable-port-hdpi` folders respectivley

**Activity:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        startApp();
    }

    private void startApp() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    HomeActivity.startHomeActivity(SplashActivity.this);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when app starts from portrait mode its works perfectly but when we start from landscape mode its start app with portrait image stretch out for few milliseconds and than it sets the landscape images like a glitch

I tried Following solutions
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736641/android-splash-screen-for-both-landscape-and-portrait-orientation)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558871/how-can-i-use-2-different-background-between-landscape-mode-and-portrait-mode)

But this solution is not suitable because it shows blanks screen in the beginning for few seconds to load the images and its takes little more time to load images from layout

Any alternate or a proper solution for this will be helpful

Comment: Solution as per Link 1 in your QUestion should work. Did you create separate folder and added layout file in it? with different image than the one in portrait one?

Comment: Yes...but as i mentioned above loading images from layout takes alot  of time result in showing blank screen for few seconds

Comment: Then perhaps you should optimize the images. It should not happen.

Comment: Images are already optimized and its works fine when we set them as background in theme...but it has a glitch problem which i have already mentioned

Comment: I see Then if you must use theme approach then Please create a separate styles.xml file into new values-land/ folder into res folder...

Comment: Why downvote ??

Comment: Believe me . I don't even remember whats going on. it was like 6 months ago.

Answer (score -1):

this is not answer of your Question But  ..

Spash screen is to wait till Activity Ready , Not to make user Wait more

so what about trying Diffrent way to make Splash screen , it`s built in

instead of white or black screen

Go to youe Manifest

change your app style like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

where splashScreenTheme is

```
<style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
```

Sure you can change parent
 and make new  drawable "Splashscreen"
this is mine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now your app Style changed 
you can reset it in your main Activity Oncreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme222);
}
```

Comment: But i want to load landscape and portrait splash as per the orientation

Answer (score -2):

If you must use theme approach then Please create a separate **styles.xml** file into new **values-land**/ folder into **res** folder... 
[image: values-land folder]

Comment: Still the same issue with glitch..first it load stretch portrait image and than after few seconds its loads landscape image

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid did you find the solution to this problem. I am also facing this issue.