# Handle Screen Orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, oncreate, landscape-portrait

When the page loads, first it loads in LANDSCAPE_MODE and then after a few seconds the orientation changes to PORTRAIT_MODE the value

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate();

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    if(orientation.equals("true")) 
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: than what is the issue

Comment: what problem are you facing? read http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/

Comment: Since your code is in **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** it doesn't wait for server's response and runs else condition OR **default condition mentioned in Manifest file** . you need to wait for server's response before proceeding with this.

Comment: check API work on PREVIOUS activity or APPLICATION class.

Comment: I already have the value from server in my POJO class.

Comment: is it because i'm setting the Orientation after setContentView?

Comment: @ShainuThomas what problem you are faciing than

Comment: The problem is when the activity opens, first the activity loads in default mode and then after few seconds the orientation changes to what is expected.

Comment: @UmairI I think you need to reconsider the Activity lifecycle again becuase onCreate() is called before onStart() https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Oh yes I forgot that my bad. :)

Comment: @Shainu set  `android:screenOrientation` to **user**  and update your preference of orientation before jumping to activity: 

**user = The user's current preferred orientation.**

For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: Thanks @SaraTirmizi . This worked for me. :).

Comment: @ShainuThomas  My pleasure, I am posting it as an answer and kindly mark that checked so that others can also get benefit from it :)

Comment: Why do you have to do that manually? Android natively handles screen rotations by itself!

Comment: I am aware of that, pertaining to my requirement, the screen should be in landscape or portrait mode irrespective of the device type.

Comment: Orientation is irrespective of device type, natively.

Comment: also in my case , once a mode is decided , it should not be changed. for example, if the mode that is expected from the server is "landscape" , the orientation should always be landscape, the user should not be able to change the orientation and the  problem in my case is that , every time the activity loads, the orientation first gets into the default mode and then after lets say 1 second, the mode changes to "landscape".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best solution for me was to handle screen orientation before calling super.onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

By default whatever the devices is in the current orientation is it will opens the activity in that mode.There is no specific way to handle this

As your changing the orientation programmatically in the activity which will be execute only after activity `onCreate()` method

So you will always face a glitch every time.I have face similar kind of orientation issue here
[Splash Screen Image for landscape and Portrait using Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042818/splash-screen-image-for-landscape-and-portrait-using-theme)

Answer (score 0):

@Shainu set

```
 android:screenOrientation = "user"
```

and

> update your preference of **orientation** before jumping to activity.
>   The user's current preferred orientation.

For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html